# Space character ignored in the linux exec file

Tags: linux, shell, exec

I was trying to run the following script

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo ${DIR}
source ${DIR}/envcov.sh
```

On echo, the output was

```
/Users/John/Desktop/Test/Test Banking/XcodeCoverage
```

When the execution reaches

```
   source ${DIR}/envcov.sh
```

I get the following error generated

```
 ./getcov: line 7: /Users/John/Desktop/Test/Test: No such file or directory
```

The space  character wasn't handled. Any idea how to overcome this issue?

**Edit**:

```
source "${DIR}/envconv.sh"
```

Adding double quotes throws me the error:

```
/Users/John/Desktop/Test/Test Banking/XcodeCoverage/envconv.sh: No such file or directory.
```

I would need to add a backspace by finding the index of the space character in the variable ${DIR} as shown below:

```
/Users/John/Desktop/Test/Test\ Banking/XcodeCoverage/envconv.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to double-quote the argument:

```
source "${DIR}/envconv.sh"
```

Comment: That line works for me, but yes, you can quote spaces with backslashes too generally. What shell are you using?

Comment: echo $SHELL gives me /bin/bash